# Building php 8 from source code sodium error

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm building PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu 18 from the source code.

This way works perfectly:

```bash
./configure --with-sodium
make
```

If I add the rest of the modules I need, I get this error:

```
./configure --with-sodium OPENSSL_CFLAGS=-I/opt/openssl/include/ 
    OPENSSL_LIBS="-L/opt/openssl/lib64/ -lssl -lcrypto" 
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig --enable-bcmath --enable-pdo --enable-soap 
    --enable-fpm --enable-intl --enable-calendar --enable-pcntl --enable-mbstring 
    --enable-sockets --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-dba --with-curl --enable-gd 
    --with-zip --with-zlib --with-iconv --with-bz2 --with-gettext --with-xml --with-mhash
    --with-xsl --with-gmp --with-ldap --with-pear --with-pgsql --with-pdo-pgsql --with-mysqli
    --with-pdo-mysql --with-openssl --with-jpeg --with-freetype --without-sqlite3 
    --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data 
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/8.1.27/lib --prefix=/usr/local/php/8.1.27

xml2 -lxml2 -lxslt -lxml2 -lexslt -lxslt -lxml2 -lzip -lz -lz -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lrt -o sapi/cli/php
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:2586: undefined reference to `crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255_base':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:2613: undefined reference to `crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255_base'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_add':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3534: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_add'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_from_hash':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3560: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_from_hash'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_add':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3624: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_add'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_invert':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3668: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_invert'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_mul':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3701: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_mul'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_sub':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3787: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_sub'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_sub':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3816: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_sub'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_is_valid_point':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3584: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_is_valid_point'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_random':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3595: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_random'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_complement':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3646: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_complement'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_negate':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3723: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_negate'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_random':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3736: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_random'
ext/sodium/libsodium.o: In function `zif_sodium_crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_reduce':
/home/php-src/ext/sodium/libsodium.c:3758: undefined reference to `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_reduce'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:314: recipe for target 'sapi/cli/php' failed
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I already tried different ways of configuring PHP.

Comment: You could try to remove the additional configure options in groups of 10 or so and then decrease the size of these groups once the error occurs. In the end, you would be able to narrow down the root cause to (hopefully) one single option. Then this is what you should look at, e. g., if the relevant libraries are installed and have the right version.